# Electron(-forge) application - understanding webpack, and how to migrate to it

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-forge

I have a feeling someone will determine that this question isn't specific enough for SO, but I really have no idea where else to turn. And all I'm looking for is some links to help get me started.

I have an electron.js application, created using electron-forge. I'd tell you what version, except I don't even know how to find that out. But I started it this year, if that helps.

In any case, when a user unzips the Windows zip distribution file, it shows something like over 4,000 files being unzipped, and it takes a while, at least in my virtual machine.

So I'd like to migrate to using webpack, because as I understand it, it will dramatically reduce the visible file count (for the most part). But I have no real idea how to go about migrating to it, nor do I even completely understand its usage in the electron-forge environment.

For example, the electron-forge documentation talks about spinning up a dev server for debugging and HMR. Do I even need this? We're talking about an electron application running on a desktop, not a server.

Anyway, any links to help get me started would be appreciated. I actually have done quite a bit of googling, but I'm still missing that one "aha!" article. Thanks.

Comment: How would you develop if you didn't have a localhost server? You can simply use Forge's webpack plugin.